# How to determine the convergence radius and interval of convergence from this sum

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I have to find the convergence radius and interval of convergence for this series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2+(-1)^n)(1+x)^{n-1}$$

I've tried the Hadamard criteria but I had no success.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Try using the root test, since $1\le2+(-1)^n\le3\implies(2+(-1)^n)^{1/n}\to1$

Comment: You could also break the sum into the even and odd terms and write it as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[(1+x)^{2k}+3(1+x)^{2k+1}\right]$ then factor out the common factor and place it in front of the sum. Then you can finish up with the geometric series test.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the series
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+x)^{n-1}$$
You know that this geometric series converges when $|1+x|<1$ or $x\in(-2,0)$. Where $S$ diverges, the original series diverges by direct comparison, or even by considering that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2+(-1)^n)(1+x)^{n-1}\ne0$$
Where $S$ converges, it does so absolutely and so does the original series by direct comparison with $3S$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: set $y=1+x$, and consider the power series with respect to $y$.